# Gradient in a plotstyle

Tags: graphics, color

I'm trying to replicate the figure below. Now a nice first approach to do this is by using *Mathematica*, by making some kind of contourplot with circles and just add a gradient to the contourstyle. Now however I'm not sure how to add a gradient to my lines, is this possible or not ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Fresnel zone]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume you're plotting a Fresnel zone plate.

```
DensityPlot[Sin[50 Sqrt[1 + x^2 + y^2]]^2, 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
 Frame -> None]
```

[image]

And if you'd like to overlap two Fresnel plates, just use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  Sin[50 Sqrt[1 + x^2 + y^2]]^2 + Sin[50 Sqrt[1 + (x + dx)^2 + y^2]]^2,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 40,
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  Frame -> None],
 {dx, 0, .5, .01}]
```

Comment: That's very correct ! :) I'm trying to make two of these images whith the necessary transparency so that I can slide them on top of eachother in order to explain interference. I should have tought indeed at the grayscale colorfunction :). Do you know if there is a way to add extra transparency for the more white parts ?

Comment: That's nice! I had not recognized the pattern that the OP desired. The `Manipulate` trick is nice as well. (+1)

Comment: "extra transparency for the more white parts" - I'm guessing you can use here the two-argument form of `GrayLevel[]` to have the alpha channel vary along with the gray.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's to use in a general presentation about light and it's wavecharacter. I'm probably going to make a presentation in powerpoint, hence the question of the transperancy. For example the figure that I gave above is a .png file with all of the white transparent. If you slide two of them over eachother you clearly see the interference pattern emerging. I try to do the presentation without mathematics because it's a presentation for high schoolers who still think math is somekind of magic ;). But indeed somekind of cutoff might work!

Comment: @Nick As a member of OSA since 1980, co-author of ***Seeing the light*** and research scientist in computational optics, I know well Fresnel zone plates.  I recommend, though, that you make a *Mathematica* Slide Show with the manipulate for your students.  I try to do as many of my interactive demonstrations in *Mathematica* as possible.  Look at the Wolfram *Demonstrations* site and search "optics" for numerous great demos you can show your students.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am well aware that the most accurate description is given by the mathematically correct superposition in stead of a simple sliding on top of eachother. However the show is given on other computers than mine, which is the reason I have to resort to powerpoint. Nevertheless it's also instructive to show them the Moiré pattern that emerges when you slide both fronts on top of eachother (which corresponds to the Huygens-idea that they than just see in high school). To answer my own question stated above Export["filename.png",fresnelplate,Background->None] will do just fine!

Comment: @Nick Any computer can run the free Wolfram CDF player.  But this is your call.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, that's true, I'm only afraid that the computers which are offered to me are not quite that fast :(. But to overcome this I can already include the datasets in the CDF of course! The best (most correct) way to include this in powerpoint is I think by eporting a .mp4-file. Then I don't need to count on the other people to pre-install the CDF player.

Answer (score 3):

I think a `ContourPlot` will do nicely here, as you suggested. The coloring can be obtained with the built-in `GrayLevel` color function.

You can choose how dense the contour lines are by either plotting over a larger domain than the unit square, or by changing the coefficients to $x^2$ and $y^2$ within the $\cos$ function. The negative sign is there to reproduce the black color of the contour at $(0,0)$.

It takes quite a few points to get a good contour; plotting took ca. 10s on my machine. You may get faster evaluation by tinkering with a combination of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` instead.

```
ContourPlot[
 -Cos[75 x^2 + 75 y^2], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}],
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
 PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 0,
 Frame -> None
]
```

[image: hypnotizing contour plot]